# Network problems on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, server, ssh, ftp, minecraft

I hired a VPS service through Contabo last week so I could ran a Minecraft server on it.

At first I installed Ubuntu 18.04 and everything was working properly, until like 2 days later that It seems that the system updated something that made my network fail. I tried to solve it but as not found the problem I reinstalled the system again, but It happened the same 2/3 days later again. 
So I decided to install Ubuntu 16.04 thinking that maybe was an OS problem. 
Once installed It happened exactly the same...

If I try to send ping from my computer I see how packets are time doubled and also many of them losts. FTP, SSH and other network services are not working. But luckily I could extract the syslog day file. At 18:48 is the hour when everything started to go down, I will paste it here shorter as It can fit:

```
May 17 18:42:01 vmi387350 CRON[13955]: (root) CMD (/etc/cron.hourly/gcc.sh)
May 17 18:45:01 vmi387350 CRON[14554]: (root) CMD (/etc/cron.hourly/gcc.sh)
May 17 18:48:01 vmi387350 CRON[15155]: (root) CMD (/etc/cron.hourly/gcc.sh)
May 17 18:48:23 vmi387350 kernel: [184072.049670] psmouse serio1: VMMouse at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost synchronization, throwing 1 bytes away.
May 17 18:48:27 vmi387350 systemd[1]: Stopped target Graphical Interface.
May 17 18:48:27 vmi387350 systemd[1]: Closed Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status /dev/rfkill Watch.
May 17 18:48:27 vmi387350 systemd[1]: Stopping ACPI event daemon...
May 17 18:48:27 vmi387350 systemd[1]: Stopped target Timers.
May 17 18:48:27 vmi387350 systemd[1]: Stopped Daily apt upgrade and clean activities.
May 17 18:48:27 vmi387350 systemd[1]: Stopped Daily Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
May 17 18:48:27 vmi387350 systemd[1]: Stopped Daily apt download activities.
May 17 18:48:27 vmi387350 systemd[1]: Stopped Message of the Day.
May 17 18:48:27 vmi387350 systemd[1]: Stopped target System Time Synchronized.
May 17 18:48:27 vmi387350 systemd[1]: Stopping Accounts Service...
May 17 18:48:27 vmi387350 systemd[1]: Stopped target Multi-User System.
May 17 18:48:27 vmi387350 systemd[1]: Stopping OpenBSD Secure Shell server...
May 17 18:48:27 vmi387350 systemd[1]: Stopping LSB: Record successful boot for GRUB...
May 17 18:48:27 vmi387350 systemd[1]: Stopping LSB: Apache2 web server...
May 17 18:48:27 vmi387350 systemd[1]: Stopping Regular background program processing daemon...
May 17 06:25:01 vmi387350 rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.16.0" x-pid="493" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] rsyslogd was HUPed
May 17 18:48:27 vmi387350 rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.16.0" x-pid="493" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] exiting on signal 15.
May 17 18:48:53 vmi387350 rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.16.0" x-pid="542" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start


...

May 17 18:48:53 vmi387350 acpid: starting up with netlink and the input layer
May 17 18:48:53 vmi387350 systemd[1]: networking.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 17 18:48:53 vmi387350 systemd[1]: Failed to start Raise network interfaces.
May 17 18:48:53 vmi387350 acpid: 1 rule loaded
May 17 18:48:53 vmi387350 acpid: waiting for events: event logging is off
May 17 18:48:53 vmi387350 systemd[1]: networking.service: Unit entered failed state.
May 17 18:48:53 vmi387350 systemd[1]: networking.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 17 18:48:53 vmi387350 systemd[1]: Reached target Network.
May 17 18:48:53 vmi387350 systemd[1]: Starting Multicraft Daemon...
May 17 18:48:53 vmi387350 systemd[1]: Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server...
May 17 18:48:53 vmi387350 systemd[1]: Reached target Network is Online.
May 17 18:48:53 vmi387350 systemd[1]: Starting /etc/rc.local Compatibility...
May 17 18:48:53 vmi387350 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Apache2 web server...
May 17 18:48:53 vmi387350 systemd[1]: Started LSB: Record successful boot for GRUB.
May 17 18:48:53 vmi387350 systemd[1]: Started /etc/rc.local Compatibility.
May 17 18:48:53 vmi387350 systemd[1]: Started Getty on tty1.
May 17 18:48:53 vmi387350 systemd[1]: Reached target Login Prompts.
May 17 18:48:53 vmi387350 apache2[636]:  * Starting Apache httpd web server apache2
May 17 18:48:53 vmi387350 accounts-daemon[532]: started daemon version 0.6.40
May 17 18:48:53 vmi387350 systemd[1]: Started Accounts Service.
May 17 18:48:53 vmi387350 systemd[1]: Started OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
May 17 18:48:53 vmi387350 systemd[1]: Reloading.
May 17 18:48:53 vmi387350 systemd[1]: Started ACPI event daemon.
May 17 18:48:54 vmi387350 systemd[1]: multicraft.service: Can't open PID file /home/minecraft/multicraft/multicraft.pid (yet?) after start: No such file or directory
May 17 18:48:54 vmi387350 systemd[1]: Started Multicraft Daemon.
May 17 18:48:54 vmi387350 apache2[636]:  *
May 17 18:48:54 vmi387350 systemd[1]: Started LSB: Apache2 web server.
May 17 18:48:54 vmi387350 systemd[1]: Reached target Multi-User System.
May 17 18:48:54 vmi387350 systemd[1]: Reached target Graphical Interface.
May 17 18:48:54 vmi387350 systemd[1]: Starting Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes...
May 17 18:48:54 vmi387350 systemd[1]: Started Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes.
May 17 18:48:54 vmi387350 systemd[1]: Startup finished in 6.856s (kernel) + 2.374s (userspace) = 9.231s.
```

And this is the /etc/network/interfaces file:

[/etc/network/interfaces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSyVW.png)

You may see that the hostname is different from one file to another, It's because I thought changing it could be one of the solutions.

Thank you in advance for the help. I am like really desperate to find the problem...

Best regards!

Comment: You might want to try just a reinstallation of your server. This question seems to be complicated enough that none of us are going to be able to help you.